# Word for cohesive, focused, all parts working towards one goal

Tags: single-word-requests

I really enjoy stories with a strong central theme, where all the character development, plot, worldbuilding etc. revolve around that one key idea or mood.

**What is a good word I can use to describe such a story?**

I want to capture the idea of 1) a strong central focus, and 2) every part having the same ultimate purpose of developing that focus. Preferably the word would have a complimentary sense to it that captures the satisfaction of the unity in such a work.

**"Cohesive"** just makes it sound like the different parts of the story work well together, not necessarily that they work well together towards a common goal.

**"Focused"** highlights how the story is very concerned with a particular subject, but not how all the different parts work together harmoniously to develop that subject.

**"Unity"** is close, but it's a kind of still, passive word; I'm not sure it adequately communicates the idea of actively working towards a common goal. It also feels strange to say that a story "has unity" or "is unified".

Sample sentence:

> "This novel is ____; every character's journey is about some aspect of responsibility."

Answer (score 3):

This could be called [artistic **unity**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=artistic%20unity&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cartistic%20unity%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: +1 Great answer. That condition of a successful literary work whereby all its elements work together for the achievement of its central purpose. In an artistically unified work nothing is included that is irrelevant to the central purpose, nothing is omitted that is essential to it, and the parts are arranged in the most effective order for the achievement of that purpose. [Source](http://www.humanitiesweb.org/spa/ltd/ID/16)

Comment: These answers are pretty coactive if you ask me.

Comment: This could be a good answer, but it needs supporting evidence that it is used in the way OP requests, rather than that it is used at all. Also, references need attributing.

Answer (score 2):

Consider [**Coaction**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/coaction) (Coactive is the adjective)

> Joint work toward a common end; collaboration, cooperation, synergy, teamwork.

"This novel is **coactive**"

If you can accept phrases too, @TimRomano has a good answer "artistic unity"

Comment: I've never heard this work before, neat! Plus one!

Comment: Very nice, I didn't know this one either.

Comment: +1 from me as well, I wasn't aware of this term. It's a lot less clunky-sounding than synergy.

Comment: Zero Google hits for 'This novel is coactive' before this post. I'd wager that 'coactive' means 'working together towards a common end', which would discount 'novel' as a possible subject. In fact, [YourDictionary](http://www.yourdictionary.com/coactive) gives 'acting in concurrence; united in action'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth **I'm aware of that.** I will remove this once there's a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try *coherent*.

> **Coherent**, definition by [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coherent)
>   2 :  having the quality of holding together or cohering; especially :  cohesive, coordinated
>   *Examples of coherent in a sentence
>   … the diaries and the novels demonstrate how a novelist tweaks and grooms reality into something more structured and coherent than life as it is lived. —Penelope Lively, Atlantic, February 2001*

The above example accompanies the dictionary entry. Here's another example from a google search of "coherent novel". Although this is a negative example (an example of a novel that is said to *not* be coherent), note the reason - it's because it fails to *interweave* the plot strands in the way you describe:

> The Times said "Yellow Dog marks a further plummeting in his literary trajectory [...] Interweaving all [the plot strands] into a compelling or indeed coherent novel proves beyond Amis's capabilities [...] Wonkily put together, his book is also copiously second-hand. Most of the material in it has been used by Amis before."
>   [- wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellow_Dog_%28novel%29), ellipses and terms quoted verbatim from wikipedia.

Your sample sentence would look like this:

> "This novel is *coherent*; every character's journey is about some aspect of responsibility."

Comment: The problem with "coherent" is that, to me, it just implies a basic level of connectedness/working together. A novel must be "coherent" to be a decent novel at all. But not all novels need to have the kind of "artistic unity" I'm trying to find a word for. (The example sentence from the Times seems to imply this, too.)

Comment: @EmilyCatáulay I see what you mean. Coherence has the required definition even in relation to artistic unity but the connotation doesn't carry so strongly. If it helps, I had in mind the notion of lasers being *coherent* light - the different 'strands' of light (speaking artistically, not scientifically) work together so effectively that the result can even cut / burn through solids.

Comment: @EmilyCatáulay What do you think of the term *teleologic*?

Comment: Calling a story "teleologic" would tend to imply that the story _as a whole_ has a purpose, not that each individual element has the same unified purpose. Close though...

Answer (score -1):

How about *symbiotic*, as in a *symbiotic relationship*?

Definition:

> **1** - Involving interaction between two different organisms living in close physical association.
>
> E.g.: The fungi form *symbiotic* associations with the roots of plant species.
>
> **1.1** - Denoting a mutually beneficial relationship between different people or groups.
>
> E.g.: The reader can have a *symbiotic* relationship with the writer.

([Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/symbiotic))

Comment: Hi, Steve. The word you nominate may very well b a good choice, but the goal of this site is to provide not merely suggestions that may be good, but suggestions backed by documented support (dictionary definitions, in the case of answers to single-word requests). To reach that standard, you would need to add a dictionary definition (citing the dictionary by name and including a link, if possible) of _symbiotic_ to your answer. The point of this standard isn't to make extra work for anwerers; it's to produce self-explanatory answers that don't require readers to go elsewhere to make sense of.

Comment: @Kyle: Nice job of filling in an appropriate definition (and crediting the source). Steve: The addition Kyle made to your answer greatly increases its completeness and authoritativeness as an answer. I hope you'll consider providing similar documentation to future answers you submit.

Answer (score -2):

The word is:
____ ***integrated***
OED:

> integrated |ˈɪntɪgreɪtɪd|
> adjective
> 1 (of an institution, body, etc.) desegregated, especially racially: integrated education.
> 2 with various parts or aspects linked or coordinated: an integrated public transport system.

***Coherent*** is also correct in the pure sense, but it is not suitable for the context given by OP.

The reason these very necessary words are unknown, is because the current "education" system suppresses the notion of Whole and Parts, and teaches people to think it terms of Parts only, divorced from the Whole that gives it context and meaning.  Integrity used to be normal.

At the end of the story, when the reader finds the plot delightful, it is precisely because the Whole has finally been exposed.  Integration is exactly what has been realised.

The notion of *teleology* is correct, it is the Final Cause, and everything does have a Final Cause, which gives the purpose of the Whole, but it is not the word being sought.